# React navigation goBack() issue

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form, react-navigation

Basically, i'm doing navigate using `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenname')` and for back functionality, I'm doing `this.props.navigate.goBack()`.
Everything is working fine as per needed except one thing that is redux state value is not fetched from state when I'm doing `goBack()` from my active screen.

Example:

In screenA : (I did this)

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB');
```

Now in screenB :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('screenC')
//...few lines as per need on my project

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        formData: state.form.ReduxFormData.values
    }
};
```

and last one screenC :

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

SO, my problem is now when i'm redirect to screenB from screenA on that time i'm able to get that state value into my formData props but when i'm goBack from screenC to screenB on that time state data is got undefined!!

Note:: I'm fetching `reduxForm` data into `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @gustavohenke on https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3372#issuecomment-326749903, please set the following property in reduxForm():-

```
destroyOnUnmount: false
```

I verified that it works.